# Converting from function- to class-based view

Tags: python, django

There is a function-based view, that looks like this:

```
def class_based_foo(request, id):
  domain = get_object_or_404(Domain, id=id)
  ..
  # here comes 20 lines of code for domain
  ..
  if request.method == 'POST':
    # do smth that requires domain
  else:
    # do smth else that also requires domain but doesn't relate to POST
return render(request, 'foo.html', {'domain': domain}
```

The question is: how to convert this to class based view?

- What generic Django view to use as the base?
- How to break it into parts, so one doesn't need to copy-paste 20 lines of domain-related code?

The idea was to:

```
class FooView(TemplateView):
  template_name = 'foo.html'

  def render_to_response(self, context, **kwargs):
    return render(self.request, self.get_template_names()[0], context)

  def get_context_data(self, domain_id, **kwargs):
    context = super(EditDomainView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    ..
    # lots of domain-related stuff
    ..
    # do smth else that also requires domain but doesn't relate to POST
    return context

  def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # do smth that requires domain
    # but where to get domain from? Copy-paste 20 lines of code again?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't convert this function into the class-based view.  Your function is clean and understandable. Class-based view will be a mess of ugly code.

If you really need to use CBV then inherit from the [UpdateView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#updateview). You can save the domain values as the attributes of `self` and then access them in various methods:

```
self.some_data = "some data"
```

It is [thread safe](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/class-based-views/#specification) operation.

Comment: Unfortunately, this has to be moved to class-based. Looks like the only was to solve it would be to move 20 ugly lines of code into function and call it.

Comment: No you can get `domain` object with `get_object()` method.  Additional data can be safely passed via attributes of `self`.